# Calling PL/SQL procedure with object Type and problems with string representation

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle, jdbc

I followed a [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html) on how to use advanced data types with JDBC and Spring, created an object type:

```
create or replace TYPE actor_type
AS OBJECT (id NUMBER(10), name VARCHAR2(50), age NUMBER);
```

Created simple procedure to add new row to an Actor TABLE:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE add_actor (in_actor IN actor_type)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT into actor (id, name, age) VALUES(in_actor.id, in_actor.name, in_actor.age);
END;
```

When I call a procedure from Java to insert new row, as explained in documentation, name column is set to "null" in DB.

However, when I change name dana type to NVARCHAR in actor type, like this:

```
create or replace TYPE actor_type
    AS OBJECT (id NUMBER(10), name NVARCHAR2(50), age NUMBER);
```

And when I execute the same code in Java to insert new row, the data gets inserted correctly, and name column is set to a value specified in Java.

I use Oracle 10g database.

What could cause this problem, and how to avoid id?